# Hide element if condition is true

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show

I have a directive which should allow me to change a specific mode, updating the scope as well.

This works fine.

The issue I'm facing now is that I need to be able to hide the element for the current mode.

I'll explain it better:

I have modes array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and some links inside an ng-repeater:

```
<a href=""
   ng-repeat="m in zoneModes"
   ng-click="changeZoneMode({{m}})"
   id="{{m}}"
   class="menu-item">
    <i class="icon-mode-{{m}}"></i>
</a>
```

what I have to do is hide an element if selectedZone is not equal to m:

```
ng-if="selectedMode!=m"
```

It seams like everything is fine doing this, but it is not.

You can clearly see what's the problem from [this live example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xdqrve?editors=1010)

Basically, everytime the condition is meet, it removes the element and never put it back.

I also tried with ng-show, but the result is not good either as it leaves an empty spot (you can check [this other example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZwLJG?editors=1010))

Any suggestions? Thanks

**EDIT**

Trying to use the filter as suggested, but with no luck:

```
.directive('mySelector', function() {
  var changeMode, linkFunction;

  changeMode = function(newmode) {
    var $scope;
    $scope = this.$parent;
    $scope.selectedMode = newmode;
    $('.menu-open').attr('checked', false);
  };
  linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.changeMode = changeMode;
    scope.changeZoneMode = changeMode;
    scope.zoneModes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    return scope.$watch((function() {
      return scope.selectedMode;
    }), function(newMode) {
      return scope.selectedMode = newMode;
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      selectedMode: '=currentmode',
      id: '@id'
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/template.html',
    link: linkFunction,
    controller: 'abc'
  };
}).controller('abc', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkM = function (mode, m) {
    return mode == m;
  };
}])
```

**template.html**

```
<a href=""
   ng-repeat="m in zoneModes|filter:checkM(selectedMode,m)"
   ng-click="changeZoneMode({{m}})"
   id="{{m}}"
   class="menu-item">
    <i class="icon-mode-{{m}}"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end , I managed to solve this using a filter, and here's the final code:

```
angular.module('App', ['ionic'])

.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.current = {
    'id': 0,
    'mode': 1
  }
}])

.directive('mySelector', function() {
  var changeMode, linkFunction;

  changeMode = function(newmode) {
    var $scope;
    $scope = this.$parent;
    $scope.selectedMode = newmode;
    $('.menu-open').attr('checked', false);
  };

  linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.changeMode = changeMode;
    scope.changeZoneMode = changeMode;
    scope.zoneModes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    return scope.$watch((function() {
      return scope.selectedMode;
    }), function(newMode) {
      return scope.selectedMode = newMode;
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      selectedMode: '=currentmode',
      id: '@id'
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/template.html',
    link: linkFunction,
  };
})

.filter('abc', function() {
        return function( m, sel ) {
          console.log('abc',arguments);
          var filteredModes = [];
          angular.forEach(m, function(mode) {
          if( sel != mode ) {
              filteredModes.push(mode);
            }
          });
          return filteredModes;
        }
    });
```

and it is now working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a **[filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)** on your `ng-repeat`? If you use a filter your element is not lost, changing the value of m will show it again. Try something like this:

```
ng-repeat="m in zoneModes|filter:checkM(selectedMode,m)"
```

Then in your controller you need to make a filter:

```
$scope.checkM = function (mode, m) {
    return mode == m;
};
```

Comment: If you use this method you need to remove your `ng-if` again.

Comment: I'm trying to use the filter, but with no luck
please see the edited question

Comment: @Nick , is it possible to make  a demo of it that i may edit? the `checkM` function might have to return a function that returns mode==m

Answer (score 0):

I might not quite understand your question but is `ng-if="selectedMode!='m'"` giving you the result you want?

Comment: except for the fact that when I change mode (for example from 1 to 2) i don'0t want 2 to be displayed, but I want 1 to be added...basically there should always be 4 icons (four different modes) but the missing one should be the selected

Comment: If i select facebook, I want to being able to see twitter, twich, vine and vk, if i select twitter, i wanna be able to see facebook, twich, vine, vk and so on..

Comment: I tried Jordan.J.D's solution and I think that this is exactly what you want.